# Unable to follow tutorial to create dynamic search results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, compiler-errors, asmx

I am following [this](http://www.magic-dev.com/autocomplete-search.htm) tutorial to create dynamic search results from an SQL server as a user types. It is telling me to create a .asmx file, which is not a format I have ever worked with before. Here is the code I have thus far :

WebService.asmx.cs :

```
public class SearchService : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public searchResult[] Search(string txtSearch)
  {
//Declare collection of searchResult
        List resultList = new List();
        var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
        var result = db.Query("SELECT * from Users where Username like '%" + txtSearch + "%'");
       try
       {
           foreach(var record in result)
            {
               searchResult result = new searchResult();
               result.Username = ["Username"].ToString();
               resultList.Add(result);
           }
           return resultList.ToArray();
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
  }}
```

WebService.asmx :

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" class="WebService.asmx.cs" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptType(typeof(searchResult))]
public class searchResult
{
    public string Title;
    public string img;
    public string href;
}
```

Here is my error message, can anyone help me with this please?

> **Compiler Error Message:** BC30689: Statement cannot appear
>   outside of a method body

Comment: Well, what are those 2 lines meant to be doing? when are they meant to be executed?

Comment: You're missing a `namespace` declaration

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you should really try and prevent SQL injection, check out this link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: @MarcGravell the class is connecting to the database and returning the information. I believe the two methods that are not working should be exposing this data to the JQuery in my webpage that calls it when a user types.

Comment: ah, they've suddenly become attributes rather than free-floating statements; that looks like a step in the right direction

Comment: @MarcGravell, thank you. I am now getting the error Compiler Error Message:BC30689: Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda. Line 2: using System;, however. Any ideas?

Comment: @Simon it has been a while, but presumably there's a different syntax for including that on a service page? something involving bee-stings, no doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web methods must be declared inside a class, and the attributes must decorate that class.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptType(typeof(searchResult))]
public class SearchService : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public searchResult[] Search(string txtSearch)
  {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have now updated my code to reflect your changes, however it is still returning the same error when I attempt to run it. Any ideas?

Comment: Compiler Error Message:BC30689: Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda.
Line 2:  using System;

Comment: I see the problem now. You are writing this code inside the .asmx file. After adding a new WebService via the Add New Item dialog, you should have a .asmx and a .asmx.cs file. Move all of the code to the .asmx.cs file, and make sure your class name matches the .asmx file name. E.g., if your filename is `SearchService.asmx`, your class should be `SearchService`.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. It is exactly what I needed to know as a complete beginner! I have tried to add what you said (see code above) and it is returning the error BC30689: Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda. for the WebService.asmx/Search function. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I have edited the code slightly and am now getting the error : Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService.asmx.cs'!

Comment: That is a different question, however, I should post it in that. Thanks very much for your help.